# Transformation of fields in 2D Dilaton Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems

In [Strominger's Lecture Notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9501071) sec 3.3 we derive the equations of motion of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and the field $\phi$  in light-cone coordinates. I understand how we get all the equations of motion and the calculation of
$$
R = \frac{4M\lambda}{M/\lambda - \lambda^2 x^+x^-}
$$

but I don't understand how we get the limit of
$$
\phi \rightarrow-\lambda\sigma-\frac{M}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda\sigma}\\
\rho \rightarrow 0 - \frac{M}{2\lambda}e^{-2\lambda\sigma}
$$
when $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}(\sigma^+-\sigma^-)\rightarrow \infty$. Where we have made a transformation
$$
\lambda x^+=e^{\lambda\sigma^+}\\
\lambda x^-=-e^{-\lambda\sigma^-}
$$

The expressions we have derived before for $\phi$ and $\rho$ (in coordinates where $\phi=\rho$) don't apply in these coordinates so my question is how to derive expressions for $\phi$ and $\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

1. To derive the asymptotic behavior of $\phi$, you have to start with the Eq.(3.17);
2. First, you should solve $\phi$ from Eq.(3.17) and replace $x_\pm$ by $\sigma$, then you arrive at $\phi = 2^{-1} \ln\left[\lambda /\left(\lambda  e^{2 \lambda  \sigma }+M\right)\right]$;
3. Second, you should manipulate this formula, such that you can expand it as $\sigma\to\infty$. $\phi=2^{-1} \ln\left[\lambda  e^{-2 \lambda  \sigma } /\left(\lambda +M e^{-2 \lambda  \sigma }\right)\right]=-\lambda  \sigma+2^{-1} \ln\left[\lambda  /\left(\lambda +M e^{-2 \lambda  \sigma }\right)\right]$;
4. We know that $\ln[\lambda/(\lambda+\epsilon)]\sim-\epsilon/\lambda +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$ at $\epsilon=0$, then applying it for $\phi$ as $\sigma\to\infty$, you can get the result.
5. As to $\rho$, I don't know how to get that $0$. If you have a better idea, please tell me.